# Execute SQL Server stored procedure in DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dbeaver

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Member_proc
    (@LastName nvarchar(50), 
     @FirstName nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        member_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender
    FROM 
        hedis_master.dbo.[Member]
    WHERE 
        first_name = @FirstName 
        AND last_name = @LastName
END;
```

Execute statement

```
Member_proc('test_e', 'test')
```

The procedure is compiled, but I'm not able to execute it.

The `Execute` command is throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Please show us the error verbatim.

Comment: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'test_e'.

Comment: [edit] into the question please.

Comment: I don't know about DBeaver, but in SSMS you would do `exec dbo.Member_proc 'test_e', 'test'` i.e. no brackets.

Comment: `FROM hedis_master.dbo.[Member]` In general you should avoid using 3-part names unless you **really** understand the consequences and you know this is needed. Presumably your stored procedure is created in the same database ("hedis") so it should select rows from within that same database. Why is this important? Imagine you add a "test" database for your system using a different name. Your procedure will not automatically update itself and will continue to select rows from original database, causing great confusion and frustration when it doesn't work at intended but throws no errors.

Answer (score 0):

CALL <schema_name>.<store_proc_name>()

Comment: Please note that code-only answers like yours usually benefit if a description of the immediate effect of what is proposed is described and explained how it helps to solve the problem.